# How to substitute all empty/blank values by "Others" in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

When I create a pie chart, I want to substitute all empty values of a field `myfield` (i.e. equal to `""`) by `"Others"`. How can I do it in Kibana?

If it's impossible to do in Kibana, then how can I do it using Elasticsearch.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I executed this query and it didn't give me any error:

```
GET myindex/entry/_update_by_query
{
  "query":{
    "term": {
      "myfield.keyword": {
        "value": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "inline": "ctx._source.myfield = 'Other'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

I get this output:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 0,
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 0,
  "version_conflicts": 0,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": []
}
```

But when I check the values of `myfield`, I get the value `""` again, instead of `Other`.

```
GET myindex/_search?
{
 "size":0,
   "aggs": {
    "months": {
     "terms" : {
      "field": "myfield"
     }
    }
   }
}
```

This is my index mapping:

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "mappings": {
      "entry": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
        "properties": {
          "Id": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "Country": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "myfield": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "Year": {
            "type":"integer"
          },
          "Counter": {
            "type":"integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done at Kibana's end. You can update all your empty field documents with "Others" in Elasticsearch index.

To update on Elasticsearch end, you can use [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). Below is the update code/query.

```
GET myindex/entry/_update_by_query
{
  "query":{
    "term": {
      "myfield": {
        "value": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "inline": "ctx._source.myfield = 'Other'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is `ctx` and `_source`?

Comment: I get `parse_exception`: `reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"`

Comment: It's Elasticsearch 5.5

Comment: I have updated my answer to meet code syntax for ES 5.5.

Comment: Please check my update, where I explain the result when I apply your query. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please paste your index mapping & also the output you get when you run my suggested query.

Comment: Try the updated query and paste the output accordingly. It should work this time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this kind of a painless script in Kibana, which will create a new string type scripted field to your index on runtime.

Select: Management -> name_of_your_index -> scripted fields -> Add Scripted field.

Next: give the script a name and set its type to "string".

Then:

```
def source = doc['name_of_the_field'].value;
if (source != null) { return source; }
else { return "Other";}
```

Then use this new field in your visualization.